# Div on('click') not working inside container

Tags: jquery, html, css

I couldn't find a working answer so I'm asking it:
Whenever I click the selected div, it just doesn't run the function.
Here's the code:

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Page Title</title>
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <textarea class="txt" onfocus="t()"></textarea>
    <div class="extension">
        <div class="dlr">$</div>
    </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
div.extension{
    position:fixed;
    left:0;bottom:0;
    width:100%;height:40px;
    background:darkgray;
}div.extension div{
    position:relative;
    left:0;top:0;
    width:25px;height:36px;
    background:white;
    border:none;border-radius:3px;
    margin:2px 0 0 8px;
    padding:0;
    font-size:1em;
    font-weight:900;
    font-family:arial;
    text-align:center;
    line-height:36px;
}.txt{
    position:absolute;
    left:0;top:0;
    width:100%;height:100%;
    border:none;border-radius:0;
    background:#222;
    color:#ccc;
    font-family:monospace;
}
```

JS:

```
$(function(){
  $('div.extension').toggle(false);
  $('.txt').blur(function(){
    $('div.extension').toggle(false);
  });
  $('div.extension div.dlr').on('click',chr);
});
function t(){
  setTimeout(a,1);
}
function a(){
  $('div.extension').css({
    top:(window.innerHeight-40)+'px'
  });
  $('div.extension').toggle(true);
}
function chr(){
  $('.txt').append('$');
  $('.txt').focus();
}
```

And here's the link:
http://www.sololearn.com/app/jquery/playground/Wq4l9mnCO460/

Ps. `<div class="dlr" onclick="chr()">$</div>` also doesn't work.

**Update:**

I probably found the problem, I just have no idea how to solve it. When I removed the `div.dlr` from the parent and placed it in the body it worked fine, but I want it to be styled relatively to the parent.

Comment: place inside a document.ready and it will run

Comment: you are also missing the parenthesis in calling chr() method

Comment: @Kurohige be more specific please

Comment: $('div.extension div.dlr').on('click',chr); should be  $('div.extension div.dlr').on('click',chr());

Comment: @Kurohige no that's not necessary

Comment: Is `div.extension div.dlr` a valid selector. I'm not sure about it.

Comment: What is supposed to happen?

Comment: @lkdhruw well, yes, it is. It does highlight when clicked

Comment: @user5014677 a $ should be added to a text area and then focus should be on that text area

Comment: Change this `$('div.extension div.dlr').on('click',chr);` to `$('div.extension div.dlr').on('click',chr());`

Comment: @msbodetti when I do that the whole code glitches. Like buttons that are focused as text inputs

Comment: @YannickMackor: Is this what you want? https://jsfiddle.net/6nuge1t1/

Comment: @SandeepNayak well, I made it on iOS for iOS and it's supposed to be a simple text editor, the problem is probably in the function or something

Answer (score 0):

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
$('div.extension div.dlr').on('click',chr);
});
```

try this

Comment: `$(function(){` is the short form of `$( document ).ready(function()` function https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/

Comment: @lkdhruw Yeah I thought it was too

Comment: then you can try using 
`$('div.extension div.dlr').click(chr);`